# Getting IO exception when running Linux command in Java

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I'm writing a java app in windows that connect to a Linux machine through SSH.
I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ssh: CreateProcess error=2, cannot find specified file.
```

Code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ls");
```

While running this command in cmd everything is working, but not through java. SSH is in my `Path` environmental vars.

Comment: What is the client OS?

Comment: Windows, as mentioned in the first line

Comment: can you pleas share full code? As in your question there is only process execution.

Comment: try using jsch for running commands over ssh. Use the `Shell` channel

Comment: Yes. I added RSA public key to my remote Linux server. The same command is running in the shell, why doesn't it running in java?

Answer (score -2):

You need an interpreter to understand *ssh* command:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ls"});
```